# How to create a search that filters by class name

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have a website that has multiple items. They are all individual div items. They all have one class name in common with several other class names as tags to help separate them (some tags are common among multiple div items)

I already have buttons set up that use data-filter=".exampleclass" and data-filter=".exampleclass2" etc. which work perfectly for sorting based on the class names. I am now trying to make a search bar where a user could type in the class name so I don't have to make buttons for them all.

```
document.getElementById("boxsearch").oninput = function() {
  var matcher = new RegExp(document.getElementById("boxsearch").value, "gi");
  for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("portfolio-item").length; i++) {
    if (matcher.test(document.getElementsByClassName("category")[i])) {
      document.getElementsByClassName("portfolio-item")[i].style.display = "inline-block";
    } else {
      document.getElementsByClassName("portfolio-item")[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kc2ot8ua/

I dont have the jquery file included so the buttons dont work (they work on my end) I just dont know how to use the search bar to search the class names.

This is the closest I could find to what I am trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/mttgj1tt/5/

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: The posted code doesn't use jQuery and you haven't included a jQuery tag. Questions asking "why doesn't this work" should include enough code **in the question** to replicate the issue. See [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @RobG You said my code doesn't use jQuery and doesn't have a jQuery tag. That doesn't make any sense, if it doesnt use jQuery then I wouldn't need the tag. I have enough code provided to answer my question.

Comment: Your code **should** include jQuery (to replicate the issue, since it is needed to make it work) and you **should** include a jQuery tag (since jQuery is needed). Also please elaborate more on how your current code is not working.

Comment: Jquery is needed for the part that already works and isnt important to the part that I need help with. I don't have a question about that part. I just need to know how to use javascript to call on class names by using a search bar. If it needs jQuery, then I don't know that.

Comment: Re "*that doesn't make any sense*". They're statements of fact and are to highlight that you mention "*I dont have the jquery file included*" but there is nothing to indicate that it's required. You should still create a minimal, complete and verifiable example, otherwise you're expecting others to also write the test code.

Answer (score 1):

Filtering elements based on regular expression matches with one of their class names is an inefficient way to filter elements. Typically you'd build an index and use that with a more optimised search algorithm.

You might use one class to select the target set of elements, then loop over them and get their classList, then loop over those looking for matches, there's an example below. But this will also test other class names that have nothing to do with filtering or sorting (e.g. in the example below, "box" is used for display only, but elements are filtered by it anyway).

A better idea might be to add the filter and sorting values as a data- attribute, then they can be isolated from other side effects. I'd also suggest building an index of subject elements so you can find the ones you want first, then hide them.

Multiple *getElementByClassName* calls are expensive and unnecessary (particularly in a for loop). The example does one call per keyup.

```js
function filterOnClass(baseClass, s) {
  let re = new RegExp(s.trim(), 'i');
  document.querySelectorAll('.' + baseClass).forEach(node => {
    let cNames = Array.from(node.classList);
    // Show all if search string is blank
    if (s.trim() == '') {
      node.classList.remove('hide');
    // Otherwise, filter 
    } else if (cNames.some(cName => re.test(cName))) {
        node.classList.add('hide');
    } else {
      node.classList.remove('hide');
    }
  });  
}
```

```css
.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="searchInput" onkeyup="filterOnClass('box', this.value)"><br>
<div class="box foo">foo</div>
<div class="box foo bar">foo bar</div>
<div class="box fum bar">fum bar</div>
<div class="box fum">fum</div>
```